# Did Batman have a thing for Wonder Woman in the New 52?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52, wonder-woman

In the New 52, when most of the Justice League is trapped inside firestorm in the *Trinity War* arc, the remaining members try to get them out by reaching out to Wonder Woman using her lasso. It was pointed out by Cyborg that Steve Trevor should be the one to do it cause there needs to be a strong connection to wonder woman, someone who has feelings for her. Yet Batman was able to reach out to her and set them free. Does it imply that he has some sort of feelings for her ?

Answer (score 1):

Batman's history in the New52 was supposed to be the same as previous, it wasn't, but it was supposed to be. This then presumes that Batman and Wonder Woman have dated at some point.

The other question requires someone to see the future and that's not a real thing so there is no answer as of yet...